# Dapper c# Inner join

Tags: c#, dapper

Hi Im trying do that query in dapper, but the list contatos return with the values null for my class Client, i don't know what i doing wrong. my class Clt_cadCliente is one Client has several contact (clt_cadContatos). Help please.

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Clt_cadCliente>();

            cn.Query<Clt_cadCliente, Clt_cadContatos, Clt_cadCliente>(@"
                            SELECT s.*, a.*
                            FROM Clt_cadCliente s
                            INNER JOIN Clt_cadContatos a ON s.IdCLiente = a.IdCliente  ", (s, a) =>
                            {
                                Clt_cadCliente shop;
                                if (!lookup.TryGetValue(s.IdCliente, out shop))
                                {
                                    lookup.Add(s.IdCliente, shop = s);
                                }
                                shop.Clt_cadContatos.Add(a);
                                return shop;
                            }, splitOn: "IdCliente").AsQueryable();

            var resultList = lookup.Values;
```

Class:

```
public partial class Clt_cadCliente
{
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdClientePai { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataNasc { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdEstCivil { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataAdm { get; set; }
    public bool Pendencias { get; set; }
    public string DescPendencia { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }
    public string PessoaFJ { get; set; }
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }
    public string CodDep { get; set; }
    public string AtivoInativo { get; set; }
    public bool Ativado { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdSitBloq { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SitBloq { get; set; }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public string NomeEsposa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> NascEsposa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdNaturezaPadrao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ViaCarteirinha { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Casa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Renda { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RendaComplementar { get; set; }
    public string Naturalidade { get; set; }
    public string Banco { get; set; }
    public string Agencia { get; set; }
    public string CidadeBanco { get; set; }
    public bool VeiculoProprio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DIB { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
    public string Nbeneficio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> LiberarExame { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidadeExame { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EnviaBoleto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> IdClienteGlobal { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Clt_cadContatos> Clt_cadContatos { get; set; }
}
```

Class 2:

```
public partial class Clt_cadContatos
{
    public int IdContato { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool AdicionarLista { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdCliente { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it of course, but I have a similar situation and if you don't insert, at least, the fields of the table `Clt_cadContatos` and in particular the name of the field `IdCliente` of this table, then the library cannot resolve the `splitOn` parameter

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Clt_cadCliente>();
cn.Query<Clt_cadCliente, Clt_cadContatos, Clt_cadCliente>(@"
    SELECT s.*, a.IdCliente, a.OtherField1, a.OtherField2, etc ....
    FROM Clt_cadCliente s
    INNER JOIN Clt_cadContatos a ON s.IdCLiente = a.IdCliente  ", (s, a) =>
    {
        Clt_cadCliente shop;
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(s.IdCliente, out shop))
        {
            lookup.Add(s.IdCliente, shop = s);
        }
        shop.Clt_cadContatos.Add(a);
        return shop;
    }, splitOn: "IdCliente").AsQueryable();
    var resultList = lookup.Values;
```

Comment: Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on the wrong parameter. You need to split on `IdContato`.

The split on field tells Dapper where one entity ends and the next begins. If you select `s.*` followed by `a.*` you want to split into a second entity on the first field of the table `a` (I'm assuming that your sql tables resemble your classes.)